# Best pattern to handle null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, gson

I am looking for best pattern to handle **NPE(Null Pointer Exception)**.
I am using retrofit for web api calls, but some times there may chance that some fields might be null, or that might be chance of null array too.
What i am looking for, is there any way to handle all in just once?.

**E.g.**

**Model Class**

```
public class ModelClass{
     String name;
     String email;
     List<Items> items;
}
```

**JSON File**

```
{
  name:null,
  email:"NPE@jvm.com",
Items:[]
}
```

So after *deserializing json* file, when i try to ***setText to textview*** **object.getName()** it will through **NPE**

I have ***very large collection of model class***, and practically it is wrong to put each field in **try{}catch()** while using it.
Is there a better way to handle this kind of scenario?.

Comment: It should return null, not throw an exception.

Comment: You don't handle NullPointerExceptions. You don't catch them. You avoid them. If a reference can be null, then you check for null before calling a method on that reference.

Comment: basically object.getName() returns null here right... what i want to do is instead of null i want to convert them into empty string or an null array list to empty arraylist..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap it around an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).  This will force you to decide at compile time what to do if the value is null.

```
Optional<String> optionalName = Optional.ofNullable(person.getName());
```

You can then decide to, for example:

- Specify a default value: `String name = optionalName.orElse("Bob");`
- Throw an exception of your choosing: `String name = optionalName.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name"));`

Comment: can i use it with android? i guess only some feature of `java 8`'s are `available` in android right now

Comment: Try it and see!  If not, the API is simple enough that you can design your own implementation of it.

Comment: Thanks man it is ***supported*** from `api level 24` in **android**.

Answer (score 0):

use Gson library to deserializing your json files and it handle the null items itself by calling serializeNulls.

this is a good guideline for Gson library(by google):
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization

Comment: hi payam,,, i have already looked into this post [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-builder-force-serialization-of-null-values).. but check email fields value it is still null... because String have default value null. so this will not help me to manage NPE

Comment: nope, it didn't because when we allow `nullable` in `GSon` it allows to take default values and String has **null** default value so it want work here..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `encapsulation`. Meaning that the variables should be `private/protected` and have public `getters` and `setters`.

Like so:

```
public class ModelClass{
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private List<Items> items;
    public ModelClass(){
        items = new List<Items>();
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name != null?name:"";
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email=null?email:"";
    }
    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email= email;
    }
    public Items getItem(int index){
        return items!=null?items.get(index):null;
    }
    public boolean addItem(Items item){
        return items!=null?items.add(item):false;
    }
}
```

As you can see the `list` will now be initialized in the `constructor`. So an outside class can only add or get `Items`. And if somehow the list is null then the `getter` and `adder` will return null and false respectively instead of throwing a `NPE`. Essentially when you are using `serialization` or `deserialization` you should initialize all `Objects` (Apart from `Strings`) inside your `constructor`. Essentially if there is a chance for a `field` to be null then you should check.

Also according to the `Java Naming Conventions` you should name the `Items class:` `Item`, `Classes` names can only be in plural if the are holding a collection of items. For example:

```
public class Item{
     private String field;
     public Item(){
          field = "hello";
     }
}

public class Items{
     private List<Item> items;
     public Items(){
          items = new List<Item>();
     }
}
```

Finally I would also recommend having a look at the `String` method: [`valueOf`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29). As you can see the method checks if the variable passed is `null` and returns the string `value` only if it isn't. You could use something similar.

Comment: what if you have 100 model class, do you have to check them in each models class's getter() setter()... do you think it is a good way to do it?

Comment: @Techierj  If you initialize every `Object` in the constructor `90%` of the times you shouldn't have a problem even without checking. (The other 10 is when you use `Objects` that might throw `Exceptions` during initialization, like `Files`, `Connections` etc.). But every `Java` project should use `Getters` and `Setters` for all `non static fields`.

Comment: Hi `optional will be helpful` for android. and thanks for ur reply though i dnt knw who downvote :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid NPE because you feel annoying, you can init value when deserializing json file by yourself. For example if deserialized name is null, just init name = "" like that. With this, you don't have to touch all model class, just modify deserializing method. This can prevent NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you do this in one place. The best way is checking null before you use that field, otherwise libs like gson would do this for you. And it's not efficient and elegant to replace all null string to "" because a json string may have deep hierarchy. So if @myoldgrandpa's answer can work, maybe that's the best way if you insist to do so.